# Race condition with multi thread and putIfAbsent

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I'm experiencing an issue with the use of putIfAbsent where the second thread will try accessing the value before the first thread has completed updating the value with a pk.

Example code.

```
public <T> Object getLookupValue(final Class<T> type, String key, ConcurrentHashMap<String, T> concurrentMap) {
        try {

            T value = concurrentMap.get(key);

            if (value == null) {
                System.out.println("save");
                T t = type.getDeclaredConstructor(String.class).newInstance(key);
                Object returnedValue = concurrentMap.putIfAbsent(key, t);

                if (returnedValue == null) {
                    System.out.println("session save");
                    session.save(t);
                    System.out.println("t ouput " + t.toString());
                    return t;
                }
                return concurrentMap.get(key);
            } else {    
                System.out.println("update" + concurrentMap.get(name));
                return concurrentMap.get(key);
            }
        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException ex) {
            System.out.println("getLookupValue " + ex);
            Logger.getLogger(LineReaderParserImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

output

```
key 2008 thread 1
save
session save
key 2008 thread 0
update Year{name =2008, pk =null}
year pk null thread 0
save
session save
t ouput Year{name =2008, pk =1}
```

Does anybody know why thread 1 is being called before thread 0 completes adding the pk or why thread 0 adds the object before the pk has been generated?

Comment: I assume that `pk` is assigned during the call to `session.save(t)`?

Comment: @MikeStrobel That is correct, hibernate assigns the pk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `ConcurrentHashMap` API:

"However, even though all operations are thread-safe, retrieval operations do not entail locking, and there is not any support for locking the entire table in a way that prevents all access."

Declare your `ConcurrentHashMap` final in your method parameters, and perform your edits on it in a synchronized block.

```
public foo(final ConcurrentHashMap concurrentMap) {
    synchronized (concurrentMap) {
        //Your code here
    }
}
```

This will force each thread to retrieve a lock on the concurrentMap `Object`, before modifying it, which will solve your race conditions.

Additionally, if you need multiple threads to access the map at the same time, but only need locking when doing the application code in the above `foo()` method, create a lock for the method to get, rather than using the map itself.

```
final Object fooLock = new Object();

public foo(final ConcurrentHashMap concurrentMap) {
    synchronized (fooLock) {
        //Your code here
    }
}
```

Bit more explanation on the second example:

Say I have a ConcurrentHashMap with a String for it's key and Year for its value. Different threads can access it to add/remove values, and I want to run an analysis on Years in a certain range while not preventing my program from adding/removing values while my analysis is running.

If a lock the ConcurrentHashMap, other threads won't be able to add/remove values until the lock is removed.

In the second example, I create a different lock for the method to grab on to, so it won't lock up the map itself.

```
ConcurrentHashMap<String, Year> concurrentMap;

final Object lock = new Object();

public void runAnalysis(final ConcurrentHashMap map) {
    /*synchronized (map) {
        //This will cause addValue() to lock up while the analysis is running
    }*/

    synchronized (lock) {
        //Now we can run a long-running analysis and not block the addValue() method

        //Additionally, if another thread calls runAnalysis(), it must wait to 
        //get our lock (when a current running analysis is completed) 
        //before it can start
    }

}

//This method needs access to concurrentMap, so we can't lock it
public void addValue() {
    concurrentMap.add("key", new Year());
}
```

Say this is all declared in a `Analyzer` class. I can also declare the runAnalysis() method like so:

```
public synchronized void runAnalysis(ConcurrentHashMap map) {
    //Do analysis logic
}
```

Instead of grabbing a lock on our "lock" Object, this method will grab the lock on the `Analyzer` instance. A slightly different way of doing it, which is usually more common than creating your own lock.

Note that if I do this, any other method that is declared "synchronized" will be blocked while runAnalysis() is running, and vice-versa. You can get as complicated as you want with locks, though if you only need *one* method for a class instance to be synchronized, it looks cleaner to grab the instance lock rather than creating a lock for the method individually.

You should look up some tutorials on multi-threading, synchronization, and locks in Java.

Comment: Thanks, Yes I need multiple threads to be able to access the maps at the sametime, could you better explain your second example? The map outside of the thread looks like this, final ConcurrentHashMap<String, Year> yearMap = getLookupMap(Year.class);

Comment: I added some more details that might shed some light on why the second one would be better

Comment: I think I'm almost comprehending this, I guess the only part I"m still not fully understanding is when to call addValue vs runAnalysis? Shouldn't I only be adding to concurrentMap when the key doesn't exist? Thanks for your help thus far.

Comment: Both of those methods are just dummy examples. It goes to prove that when using a lock on an Object or the class instance, you can still modify/read the ConcurrentMap. If you lock the ConcurrentMap, you won't be able to modify/read it at all from other threads.